# C socket program as web server to run in cloud, not receiving any response from browser

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming, webserver

I'm trying to develop a web server program using C++ that is suppose to run on a cloud machine running amazon machine. I wrote a code in C, but it won't receive any response from the web browser when the IP address and port number are entered in the address bar. However, it receives a response from `localhost`. Here's my source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc , new_socket , c;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
char *message;

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}


server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8080 );

//Bind
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("bind failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

listen(socket_desc , 3);

puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
while( (new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c)) )
{
    puts("Connection accepted");

    //Reply to the client
    message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. But I have to go now, bye\n";
    write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));
}

if (new_socket<0)
{
    perror("accept failed");
    return 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

Is there any logical problem in my source code?

Comment: Did you check the amazon firewall settings? I think it is called security group or something similar

Comment: its all are correct i have implemented a python server in this same machine

Comment: try port 80 instead of port 8080 . I had a similar problem last week and i tried from another system and it worked .

Comment: Was python server also using 8080? Did the server have issues with `bind()` call? Did you perform packet captures to see if the `SYN` from your browser's machine was reaching your amazon machine?

Comment: @SanthoshPai when i changed 8080 to 80 ,i got an error of bind  "failed " ,prinf is executed and returned .

Comment: @jxh python server was using python flask

Comment: This might not be related but still is dangerous: `.... (socklen_t*)&c))` with `int c;`. Consider declaring `c` as `socklen_t`. It's dangerous as `socklen_t` might be of different size than `int`. Also the code is missing error checking for the call to `listen()`.

Comment: Do you see the `Connection accepted` on the server side?

Comment: You will probably not be able use port 80, they are usually reserved to standard services in unix, above 2000 should not cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code on a CentOS 6.4 machine.  It worked... I had "Connection Accepted" from

```
"http://localhost:8080"
```

and from another machine on the network, I entered

```
"http://192.168.2.22:8080"
```

and got a "Connection Accepted" on the Linux console. Also, both IP address and "localhost" worked from the machine running the program.  I'm pretty sure it's a network issue.

But try changing your code a bit just for the heck of it...

Try this:

change:

```
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
```

to:

```
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , IPPROTO_TCP);
```

add:

```
close(new_socket);
```

after:

```
write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));
```

and once again, for the heck of it...
add:

```
memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
```

before you use your server struct.

Comment: for the heck of what?! please be precise and mention the reason for the change you offer. There's no such thing as "heck of it" in computer science. There's a reason for everything. Please fix it to avoid down vote.

Answer (score 0):

you check the firewall settings of running host.

if it is linux, use command

`netstat -atnp`  - to see your program is opened the desired port (8080) or not.

`service iptables stop` - to stop firewall in old versions

`systemctl stop firewalld` - to stop firewall in latest versions

enable firewall again once you completed testing your program by replacing `stop` by `start`.

or allow TCP port 8080 in firewall settings if you want to permanently use that port